# Proofs for if $\widetilde X\rightarrow X$ is a modification & $\widetilde X$ is a $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold, then so is $X$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

A celebrated result due to Deligne--Griffiths--Morgan--Sullivan (see Theorem 5.22 in [Real Homotopy Theory of Kaehler Manifolds](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389853)) says that:

> Consider a proper modification $f:\widetilde M\rightarrow M$ between two compact complex manifolds. Suppose that the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma holds on $\widetilde M$, then so does on $M$.

Recall that we say a compact complex manifold $X$ satisfies $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma (or say $X$ is a  $\partial\bar{\partial}$-manifold if for any $d$-closed pure type form $\alpha$ on $X$, one has
$$\alpha\text{ is } d\text{-exact}\iff \alpha\text{ is } \partial\text{-exact}\iff\alpha\text{ is } \bar\partial\text{-exact}\iff \alpha\text{ is } \partial\bar{\partial}\text{-exact}.$$

Deligne et at. proved the above lemma with the aid of the following idea: use Serre duality to prove that
$$f^*:H^*(M,\Omega^*)\rightarrow H^*(\widetilde M,\Omega^*)$$
is a split injection. Thus the Frohlicher spectral sequence for $\widetilde M$
contains that of $M$ as a direct summand.

I aim to prove the previous lemma in  a different approach as follows:

> Fix a proper modification $f:\widetilde M\rightarrow M$ and let $\alpha\in A^{p,q}(M)$. Suppose that $d\alpha=0$, then so is $\widetilde\alpha:=f^*\alpha.$ Now suppose that $\alpha$ is $d$-exact, we are going to show that it is also $\partial\bar{\partial}$-exact. To see this, one first observes that $\widetilde\alpha$ is also $d$-exact, then applies  $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma to conclude that there exists  $\widetilde\beta\in A^{p-1,q-1}(\widetilde M)$ such that
> $$\widetilde \alpha=\partial\bar{\partial}\widetilde \beta.$$ Then, by using the commutativity of direct image and differential operators on the *current*, we obtain
> $$\alpha=f_*\widetilde \alpha=f_*\partial\bar{\partial}\widetilde \beta=\pm\partial\bar{\partial}f_*\beta.$$
> In other words, $[\alpha]=[0]$ in $H^{p,q}_\textrm{BC}(M)$, we then get the desired result by noticing that the Bott-Chern cohomology groups can be computed either by smooth forms or by currents on a compact complex manifold. The rest of the directions are similar, since other than the Bott-Chern groups, the De-Rham/Dolbeault cohomology groups can also be computed either by smooth forms or by currents.

---

Here is my questions:

**Q1:** Is my proof correct？

Another motivation of this post lies in the following:

There exists a class of $\partial\bar\partial$-manifolds, namely the Fujiki class $\mathscr C$. A compact complex manifold $X\in\mathscr C$ if  it is the meromorphic image of a
compact Kähler manifold, or equivalently it is bimeromorphic to
a compact Kähler manifold. Demailly-Paun also gives a useful criterion saying that  there exists a Kähler current $T$  on $X$ (i.e., $T\geq\epsilon\omega$ as a current with $\omega$ being a not necessarily closed smooth Hermitian form)  $\iff$ $X\in\mathscr C$.

Here appears my second question:

**Q2:** So, for a manifold $X$ in the Fujiki class, can one give another proof, besides DGMS's and mine (if it's correct), to see $X$ satisfies the $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma by use of the Demailly-Paun's criterion?